# Best practice on storing the path of an AJAX uploaded file in DB

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I have a form that has both form data and file upload and I want to do the upload via AJAX.

How should I store the path of the file in DB?

1) On `create` request just show the form  and when the file is uploaded return the path to the form and send it back when the form is submitted?

2) On `create` request, create a new record too and store the path of the file in the record when it is uploaded

Comment: I wouldn't store the whole path in database, even if the uploaded files are stored in different folders. So, only file reference goes in database, at least in my case.

Comment: @hex494D49 Am I clear about my Q? I want to know whether I should create the record that holds the path/reference in advance or not?

Comment: Well, that's why I commented only the part I understood ;) I see, of course not. Upload the file, give it a unique name and store the reference in database (if everything went fine) and send back the reference in order to show the file (or thumbnail) to the user. At least this is my approach.